# Possibility to use st_intersection or st_intersects with more than two layers?

Tags: qgis, dbmanager

I work on Qgis with DB manager. I have multiple layers on different themes, for example wet areas, ecological corridors, and so on.

I would like to know which theme layer is intersecting with my project layer (which contains different sectors). I've already started to try out some requests to see what it would come up with, I used st_intersects and st_intersection, and I would like to know if it's possible to use more than 2 layers with these functions.

Basically I would like to have a list of every theme layer that intersects with my different porject sectors instead of using "OR".

Comment: You are using Virtual layers, or is it a PostGIS database you are querying?

Comment: You can create a SQL `SELECT` with all your theme layers with `UNION ALL` : `SELECT 'corridors' AS theme, geom FROM corridors_layer UNION ALL SELECT 'wet_areas', geom FROM wet_areas_layer` and intersects this `SELECT` just once.

Answer (score 1):

To simply get a `BOOLEAN` value for each *theme* layer that intersects your *project* layer in *any* way, use a fast `EXISTS` selection each:

```
SELECT
  prj.*,
  EXISTS(
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      <theme_1> AS t1
    WHERE
      ST_Intersects(prj.<geom>, t1.<geom>)
  ) AS t1_intersects,
  ...,
  EXISTS(
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      <theme_n> AS tn
    WHERE
      ST_Intersects(prj.<geom>, tn.<geom>)
  ) AS tn_intersects
FROM
  <project_layer> AS prj
;
```

This is cross-backend - *SQLite/SpatiaLite* (including *Virtual Layers*) & *PostgreSQL/PostGIS* - but you will have to change the `<geom>` column identifier accordingly (i.e. *Virtual Layers* usually defaults to `geometry`).

Note that you will have to add an `EXISTS` select for each of your *theme* layers - there is no other way than a sub-query for each layer if *pivoting* this into the result set is what you are looking for. And FYI: *SQLite/SpatiaLite* returns a *boolean* `INTEGER` here.

---

You can achieve a row based aggregation of values from the *theme* layers with an explicit sub-query, i.e.

```
SELECT
  prj.*,
  (
    SELECT
      <value_aggregator>
    FROM
      <theme_1> AS t1
    WHERE
      ST_Intersects(t1.<geom>, prj.<geom>)
  ) AS <intersection_aggregates>,
  ...
FROM
  <project_layer> AS prj
```

but the `<value_aggregator>` implementation is specific to the backend you are using.

---

Additionally, *PostgreSQL/PostGIS* offers the very flexible and fast `LATERAL` join which would allow you to also expand sub-query result sets into the main result set on a per row basis if needed.